# "Divinity: Original sin" game tries to load outdated libicuuc library

Tags: libraries, games

The game is Divinity: Original sin

I was missing a few of the libraries it needs to run, one of which was libicuuc.so.54. I tried to update libicuuc but the version installed was .55, and the game doesn't detect it.

> ./EoCApp: error while loading shared libraries: libicuuc.so.54: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

How do I get the proper version of libicuuc installed or force the game to use the newer version?

Comment: Show us your `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, `cat /etc/ld.so.conf`, and where the file is located (you could search it with `find /usr -name libicuuc.so.54`).